# jquery get json and returns first as a label?

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I have Google'd this thing to death, lots of people are having the same problem but the common fix isn't working for me..

My data which is returned from my home server:

```
{
  "errors": 1.15,
  "allErrors": null,
  "threads": 10.83,
  "sale": 131.36,
  "delivery": 1.68,
  "failed": 60,
  "webErrors": 432,
  "webErrorsByMin": 0
}
```

I have tried:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://srv3.localhost:8080/monitor/Totals?callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                    }); 
                    }
            }, "jsonp");
```

I have also tried:

```
$.getJSON("http://srv3.localhost:8080/monitor/Totals?callback=?",
                    function(data){

                        var result = eval( "(" + data + ")" );
                });
```

It keeps trying to set the first key as a label..

Firefox error:

```
invalid label
"address": 1.8,
```

I have tried so many different things but always it comes back as a label..  After my google searches, the common fix was to encapsulate the return using:

```
var result = eval( "(" + data + ")" );
```

But its not working in my case..  :(

Anyone know why this isn't working for me?  Using jquery 1.4.2

Thanks!

Comment: That's not JSONP.  You need to make the server-side return a valid statement.

Comment: I tried using "json" with no luck as well..

Comment: You must use JSONP to make a cross-domain request.   You need to learn what JSONP is.

Answer (score 1):

For Tomcat servlet side, you need a filter to tranforme the response. How to program a filter, you can find in Tomcat side examples. A good starting point is:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe the results get obfuscated to `data.d`.

You can verify this by taking a look at the JSON return using Firebug and doing a net capture of the request and response.

Comment: data.d is when the json requested is coming from a windows server?  I'm using Apache-Coyote/1.1.  I did check the net and response in firebug, looks exactly like the above data example and the net json tab is just the keys, values (exactly how I want to use them! lol)

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ?

```
for (var key in data){
  items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + data[key] + '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning JSON from your server and assuming you are doing a cross-domain call and that's why you need a JSONP request.

You need to wrap your JSON data into a function that you passed through parameter `callback`.

Your JavaScript code seems to be quite fine but your server code needs to be doing something like this:

```
HandleRequest()
BEGIN
   callbackFunction = REQUEST.PARAMETER["callback"]
   RESPONSE.WRITE callbackFunction + "(" + jsonSerializedData + ")"
END
```

*PS: You don't need to do JSONP request if you are requesting on the same server.*

Comment: That's cross-domain access policy. You server must provide function definition to work against JSONP